# CodeBlocks linker issue with MySQL on Windows 10

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

I am trying to connect to my remote database MySQL server. I am using C++ in the CodeBlocks 17.12 IDE on Windows 10 Enterprise with MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9.

Following are my build options.

[image: Search Directories]

I used this code to test the connection:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlcppconn.lib")
const string server   = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3310";
const string username = "user";
const string password = "password"; 
int main()
{
    sql::Driver     *driver; 
    sql::Connection *dbConn;  
    object
    sql::Statement  *stmt;   
    sql::ResultSet  *res;    
    try
    {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not get a database driver. Error message: " << 
        e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
   }
   // Try to connect to the DBMS server
   try
   {
       dbConn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
   }
   catch (sql::SQLException e)
   {
       cout << "Could not connect to database. Error message: " << e.what() 
       << endl;
       system("pause");
       exit(1);
   }
   stmt = dbConn->createStatement();
   try
   {
       stmt->execute("USE teste");            
       res = stmt->executeQuery("show tables"); 
   }
   catch (sql::SQLException e)
   {
       cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
       system("pause");
       exit(1);
   }
   while (res->next())
   {
      cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
   }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete dbConn;  
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors.

[image]

How to fixed this ?

Update

[image]

Comment: This is not a linker issue. It is a compilation issue. Most likely you need to define something to prevent MySQL headers from redeclaring standard types.

Comment: Okay, but there is nothing in docs the mysql connector. Any Ideas?

Comment: Look at that `config.h` and check whether those declarations are part of some conditional compilation block.

Comment: I post imagem  my config.h lines, yes is conditional compilation.
Should I comment?

Comment: No, you need to make sure that those `HAVE_MS_INT32` macros are not defined.